# private controller actionresult with outputcache

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I have a public actionresult which I would like to use as a sort of pre-processor for work before handing off to a private action result. I'm planning on using the first controller action to make a call to an external API which places the requesting IP address on a scale measuring potential fraudulent activity of that address. The possible levels that may be returned by this API call are `Low`, `Medium`, `High`.

The general idea of what I'm thinking is as follows:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RiskCheck(string id, int page) {
    // Check risk for request with external API 
    var riskLevel = await SomeRiskCheckAsync();

    return PageOutput(id, page, riskLevel);
}

[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, Duration = Int32.MaxValue, VaryByParam = "id;page;riskLevel")]
private async Task<ActionResult> PageOutput(string id, int page, string riskLevel) {
    if (riskLevel.Equals("Low") {
        return View("Low_Risk");
    } else if (riskLevel.Equals("Medium")) {
        return View("Medium_Risk");
    } else {
        return View("High_Risk");
    }
}
```

The end goal is that there will be 3 cached views corresponding to each unique combination of id and page such that I can alleviate the need to continuously re-render views which will always be the same output.

I have two questions about this approach. First, when applied to a private method like this will the output actually be cached or does it need to be a traditional client facing action result?

Second, I feel like I might be able to combine both views into one if I were able to use a `VaryByCustom` guard on `RiskCheck` and use that custom override to check the risk ahead of time. This is actually the approach I went for first. However when I went to override  `GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)` I realized that there is no async version provided.

```
public override GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom) {
     // Can't await this result
    var riskLevel = await SomeRiskCheckAsync(); 
    return riskLevel;
}
```

I can't afford to not be able to keep this part of the application asynchronous as it will be hit frequently.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:

No the output caching will not be applied. The attribute has to be on the actual public action method because that is all the MVC framework knows about and has the ability to interrogate, whereas MVC knows nothing about your call to `PageOutput` and even if it did it's arguable what it should do with that piece of information i.e. what if there was another call to another private function with different output cache settings... things could get out of hand rather quickly.

My opinion on the second question:

I think you might be using the async framework for the hell of it, not to solve a problem :) You probably should think about getting rid of it to make life easier. As for combining the views into one, that is something that I'd need more clarification about what the views contain and how likely they are to differ from one another over time as functionality is increased in the product spec.